# not able to install 2.3.0 : Invalid template file

Tags: magento2.3.0

Issue

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid
>   template file:
>   'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml'
>   in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(249): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#12 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to install Magento2 with a **custom module** that extends some js files.

> Try installing Magento using **original Magento 2 CE files**. Then **install** your **custom module** **after successful installation**.